# add personal template directory to poly-R

Tags: ess, polymode

I'm trying to migrate my R workflow totally to emacs (my experience with emacs is very basic), so I installed ESS and `poly-markdown` and `poly-R` among other things.

When working in rmarkdown files I wanted some personal templates I have in a personal directory to be listed **along** the templates offered by installed R packages (tufte, pagedown, etc.).

I couldn't find how to do it, so I ventured to add this to my `.emacs` file, thinking that it would add to the path to search for such templates:

```
(setq poly-r-rmarkdown-template-dirs "/home/my-user-here/path-to-RmdTemplates/")
```

When I restart emacs, and open an .Rmd file I can see the "Rmarkdown > Templates" menu, but it's not populated (completely empty). When I comment the above mentioned line in `.emacs` (with `;;` and restart emacs), the menu is populated with the templates provided by the installed packages (tufte, pagedown, xaringan, etc.).

How can I "add" my personal directory to those where `poly-R` looks for templates?

Comment: Is this something related to https://github.com/polymode/poly-R/issues/20? Have you checked whether the menu "is populated after an R process is associated with the current buffer"? (Otherwise, although the docstring says absolutely nothing about that, maybe you should try to provide a list instead of a string. I.e., `(setq poly-r-rmarkdown-template-dirs '("/home/my-user-here/path-to-RmdTemplates/"))`. Sometimes, such custom variables expect actually a list.)

Comment: @Philopolis I had read the issue 20 you linked before posting here, and it certainly helped me understand why the menu was empty initially. But as plantarum said there, I only needed to associate an R process to the current buffer, and the menu was populated. OTH, providing a list `'("path/to/folder/")` did not help: only package templates are shown in the menu.